# How set android:layout_marginBottom programm?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-layoutparams

To drag the Image on the screen I created my own class:

```
private class CustomImageView extends AppCompatImageView
```

In the constructor I want to set params:

```
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.bottomMargin = 50;
    this.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
}
```

my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eleizo.firstapplication.MainActivity">   
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to have actually as it would be :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eleizo.firstapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Why string `"params.bottomMargin = 50"` doesn't work? I tried to set `params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(val1,val2)` but it's no matter.
How set `android:layout_marginBottom` in RelativeLayout by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the LayoutParams while you are adding the view in the relative layout. [ViewGroup.addView(View, LayoutParams)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) .

Something like this.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.bottomMargin = 50;

relativeLayout.addView(new CutomImageView(context), params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MarginLayoutParams` instead of `LayoutParams`.

```
if( params instanceof MarginLayoutParams )
{
    ((MarginLayoutParams) params).bottomMargin = 50;
    ((MarginLayoutParams) params).leftMargin = 10;

}
```

So your code would look like

```
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    if( params instanceof MarginLayoutParams )
    {
    ((MarginLayoutParams) params).bottomMargin = 50;
    }
    this.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);
```

}